# How to pass the string and get their data after clicking the item in an listview,it has to take their respective data according to the click item

Tags: java, android

I have a listview and in that listview if an item is clicked, it has to select their respective data and display it,how to pass the data as a sting and how to fetch that one? For me I passed the name argument,it has to compare the name and fetch the data to display it.

how to pass string in FirstActivity.java?

```
public class SouthIndianvegrecipes1  extends Activity {

 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ArrayList<Recipedetails> image_details = GetSearchResults();

        final ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listV_main);
        lv1.setAdapter(new ItemListBaseAdapter(this, image_details));

        lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) { 
                Object o = lv1.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Recipedetails obj_itemDetails = (Recipedetails)o;
                Toast.makeText(SouthIndianvegrecipes1.this, "You have chosen : " + " " + obj_itemDetails.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 Intent newActivity = new Intent(SouthIndianvegrecipes1.this, 
                            SouthIndianvegmanualrecipes.class );  
                newActivity.putExtra("name", obj_itemDetails.getName());
                            startActivity(newActivity);

            } 
        });
    }

    private ArrayList<Recipedetails> GetSearchResults(){
        ArrayList<Recipedetails> results = new ArrayList<Recipedetails>();

        Recipedetails item_details = new Recipedetails();
        item_details.setName("Godhumai veg adai");
        item_details.setItemDescription("This is very good for dibets people");
        //item_details.setUrlWiki("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C_r0mFvMSfU");
        item_details.setImageNumber(12);
        results.add(item_details);

        item_details = new Recipedetails();
        item_details.setName("Soyamore koozh");
        item_details.setItemDescription("Tasty to have this as main dish");
        //item_details.setUrlWiki("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C_r0mFvMSfU");
        item_details.setImageNumber(13);
        results.add(item_details);

        item_details = new Recipedetails();
        item_details.setName("Tomato kulambu");
        item_details.setItemDescription("Good side dish for rice and dinner");
        //item_details.setUrlWiki("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C_r0mFvMSfU");
        item_details.setImageNumber(14);
        results.add(item_details);

        item_details = new Recipedetails();
        item_details.setName("Tomato upma");
        item_details.setItemDescription("Evening time  dinner for kids");
        //item_details.setUrlWiki("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C_r0mFvMSfU");
        item_details.setImageNumber(15);
        results.add(item_details);




        item_details = new Recipedetails();
        item_details.setName("Navratri special vada");
        item_details.setItemDescription("Good snacks at the function");
        //item_details.setUrlWiki("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C_r0mFvMSfU");
        item_details.setImageNumber(16);

        results.add(item_details);


        item_details = new Recipedetails();
        item_details.setName("Egg kurma");
        item_details.setItemDescription("Wonderful dish made by egg");
        //item_details.setUrlWiki("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C_r0mFvMSfU");
        item_details.setImageNumber(17);
        results.add(item_details);

        item_details = new Recipedetails();
        item_details.setName("Milagu kuzhambu");
        item_details.setItemDescription("Good for digestion purpose");
        //item_details.setUrlWiki("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C_r0mFvMSfU");
        item_details.setImageNumber(18);
        results.add(item_details);

        item_details = new Recipedetails();
        item_details.setName("Rasam");
        item_details.setItemDescription("Last and famous dish in lunch,good for health also");
        //item_details.setUrlWiki("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C_r0mFvMSfU");
        item_details.setImageNumber(19);
        results.add(item_details);

        item_details = new Recipedetails();
        item_details.setName("Vegetable kootu");
        item_details.setItemDescription("Nice and healthy one");
        //item_details.setUrlWiki("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C_r0mFvMSfU");
        item_details.setImageNumber(20);
        results.add(item_details);

        item_details = new Recipedetails();
        item_details.setName("Avial");
        item_details.setItemDescription("Easy to prepare and lots of vegetable");
        //item_details.setUrlWiki("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C_r0mFvMSfU");
        item_details.setImageNumber(21);
        results.add(item_details);

        item_details = new Recipedetails();
        item_details.setName("kothavarangaicurry");
        item_details.setItemDescription("Tamilnadu special and healthy too");
        //item_details.setUrlWiki("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C_r0mFvMSfU");
        item_details.setImageNumber(22);
        results.add(item_details);


        return results;
    }
```

}

second activity

```
public class SouthIndianvegmanualrecipes  extends Activity {

    @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.recipe_manual);
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            String value = intent.getStringExtra("name");


           if(value.equals("Godhumai veg adai"))
        {
            Recipedetails2 item_details = new Recipedetails2();
            item_details.setName("Godhumai veg adai");
            item_details.setIngredients("This is very good for dibets people");
            item_details.setMethods("This is very good for dibets people");

        }
        else if(value.equals("Soyamore koozh"))
        {
            Recipedetails2 item_detail1 = new Recipedetails2();
            item_detail1.setName("Soyamore koozh");
            item_detail1.setIngredients("Tasty to have this as main dish");
            item_detail1.setMethods("This is very good for dibets people");
        }
        else if(value.equals("Tomato kulambu"))
        {
            Recipedetails2 item_detail3 = new Recipedetails2();
            item_detail3.setName("Tomato kulambu");
            item_detail3.setIngredients("Good side dish for rice and dinner");
            item_detail3.setMethods("This is very good for dibets people");

        }
        else if(value.equals("Navratri special vada"))
        {
            Recipedetails2 item_detail5 = new Recipedetails2();
            item_detail5.setName("Navratri special vada");
            item_detail5.setIngredients("Good snacks at the function");
            item_detail5.setMethods("This is very good for dibets people");

        }
        else if(value.equals("Egg kurma"))
        {
            Recipedetails2 item_detail6 = new Recipedetails2();
            item_detail6.setName("Egg kurma");
            item_detail6.setIngredients("Wonderful dish made by egg");
            item_detail6.setMethods("This is very good for dibets people");

        }
        else if(value.equals("Milagu kuzhambu"))
        {
            Recipedetails2 item_detail7 = new Recipedetails2();
            item_detail7.setName("Milagu kuzhambu");
            item_detail7.setIngredients("Good for digestion purpose");
            item_detail7.setMethods("This is very good for dibets people");

        }

        else if(value.equals("Rasam"))
        {
            Recipedetails2 item_detail8 = new Recipedetails2();
            item_detail8.setName("Rasam");
            item_detail8.setIngredients("Last and famous dish in lunch,good for health also");
            item_detail8.setMethods("This is very good for dibets people");

        }

        else if(value.equals("Vegetable kootu"))
        {
            Recipedetails2 item_detail9 = new Recipedetails2();
            item_detail9.setName("Vegetable kootu");
            item_detail9.setIngredients("Nice and healthy one");
            item_detail9.setMethods("This is very good for dibets people");

        }

        else if(value.equals("Avial"))
        {
            Recipedetails2 item_detail10 = new Recipedetails2();
            item_detail10.setName("Avial");
            item_detail10.setIngredients("Easy to prepare and lots of vegetable");
            item_detail10.setMethods("This is very good for dibets people");

        }

        else 
        {
            Recipedetails2 item_detail11 = new Recipedetails2();
            item_detail11.setName("kothavarangaicurry");
            item_detail11.setIngredients("Tamilnadu special and healthy too");
            item_detail11.setMethods("This is very good for dibets people");

        }



        }
    }
```

here i need to put or store string functionality to put their name and images and ingredients and methods according to my layout,after the if function i put the wrong codes,
layout.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"

  android:orientation="vertical"

  >

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/photo"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:scaleType="center"
  ></ImageView>

  <TextView android:id="@+id/name"
        android:textSize="14sp" 
        android:textStyle="bold" 
        android:textColor="#32cd32" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/photo"/>

  <TextView
      android:text="Ingredients:"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:gravity="left" />

  <TextView android:id="@+id/itemIngredients"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="center" />

   <TextView
      android:text="Method:"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:gravity="left" />

  <TextView android:id="@+id/methods"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

How to pass a string and how to compare and fetches and display it? or can you give some links how to do that one?

**Is it my code is comparing and why its not displaying their data,it is dispalying only the default layout**

Answer (score 0):

**Friends this is the correct code its working**

```
 public class SouthIndianvegmanualrecipes  extends Activity {
TextView itemName,itemIngredients,methods;
ImageView itemImage;
String value;


private Integer[] imgid = {
        R.drawable.vegeterian,
        R.drawable.nonveg,
        R.drawable.pickels,
        R.drawable.soup,
        R.drawable.sweets,
        R.drawable.cakes,
        R.drawable.icecreams,
        R.drawable.chinesevegdishes,
        R.drawable.chinesenonveg,
        R.drawable.chinesenoodles,
        R.drawable.chinesesoup,
        R.drawable.godhumaivegadai,
        R.drawable.soyamorekoozh,
        R.drawable.tomatokulambu,
        R.drawable.tomatoupma,
        R.drawable.vadanavratrispecial,
        R.drawable.eggkurma,
        R.drawable.milagu,
        R.drawable.rasam,
        R.drawable.vegetablekootu,
        R.drawable.avial,
        R.drawable.kothavarangaicurry,
        };



    @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.recipe_manual);
            Intent intent = getIntent();
             value = intent.getStringExtra("name");
                itemName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
                itemIngredients = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.itemIngredients);
                methods = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.methods);
                itemImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.photo);

           if(value.equals("Godhumai veg adai"))
        {
            Recipedetails2 item_details = new Recipedetails2();
            item_details.setName("Godhumai veg adai");
            item_details.setIngredients("This is very good for dibets people");
            item_details.setMethods("This is very good for dibets people");
            item_details.setImageNumber(12);
            setUIScreen(item_details.getName(),item_details.getIngredients(),item_details.getMethods(),item_details.getImageNumber() );
        }
        else if(value.equals("Soyamore koozh"))
        {
            Recipedetails2 item_detail1 = new Recipedetails2();
            item_detail1.setName("Soyamore koozh");
            item_detail1.setIngredients("Tasty to have this as main dish");
            item_detail1.setMethods("This is very good for dibets people");
            item_detail1.setImageNumber(13);
            setUIScreen(item_detail1.getName(),item_detail1.getIngredients(),item_detail1.getMethods(),item_detail1.getImageNumber() );
        }
        else if(value.equals("Tomato kulambu"))
        {
            Recipedetails2 item_detail3 = new Recipedetails2();
            item_detail3.setName("Tomato kulambu");
            item_detail3.setIngredients("Good side dish for rice and dinner");
            item_detail3.setMethods("This is very good for dibets people");
            item_detail3.setImageNumber(14);
            setUIScreen(item_detail3.getName(),item_detail3.getIngredients(),item_detail3.getMethods(),item_detail3.getImageNumber() );

        }
        else if(value.equals("Tomato upma"))
        {
            Recipedetails2 item_detail4 = new Recipedetails2();
            item_detail4.setName("Tomato upma");
            item_detail4.setIngredients("Good side dish for rice and dinner");
            item_detail4.setMethods("This is very good for dibets people");
            item_detail4.setImageNumber(14);
            setUIScreen(item_detail4.getName(),item_detail4.getIngredients(),item_detail4.getMethods(),item_detail4.getImageNumber() );

        }

        else if(value.equals("Navratri special vada"))
        {
            Recipedetails2 item_detail5 = new Recipedetails2();
            item_detail5.setName("Navratri special vada");
            item_detail5.setIngredients("Good snacks at the function");
            item_detail5.setMethods("This is very good for dibets people");
            item_detail5.setImageNumber(15);
            setUIScreen(item_detail5.getName(),item_detail5.getIngredients(),item_detail5.getMethods(),item_detail5.getImageNumber() );
        }
        else if(value.equals("Egg kurma"))
        {
            Recipedetails2 item_detail6 = new Recipedetails2();
            item_detail6.setName("Egg kurma");
            item_detail6.setIngredients("Wonderful dish made by egg");
            item_detail6.setMethods("This is very good for dibets people");
            item_detail6.setImageNumber(16);
            setUIScreen(item_detail6.getName(),item_detail6.getIngredients(),item_detail6.getMethods(),item_detail6.getImageNumber() );
        }
        else if(value.equals("Milagu kuzhambu"))
        {
            Recipedetails2 item_detail7 = new Recipedetails2();
            item_detail7.setName("Milagu kuzhambu");
            item_detail7.setIngredients("Good for digestion purpose");
            item_detail7.setMethods("This is very good for dibets people");
            item_detail7.setImageNumber(17);
            setUIScreen(item_detail7.getName(),item_detail7.getIngredients(),item_detail7.getMethods(),item_detail7.getImageNumber() );
        }

        else if(value.equals("Rasam"))
        {
            Recipedetails2 item_detail8 = new Recipedetails2();
            item_detail8.setName("Rasam");
            item_detail8.setIngredients("Last and famous dish in lunch,good for health also");
            item_detail8.setMethods("This is very good for dibets people");
            item_detail8.setImageNumber(18);
            setUIScreen(item_detail8.getName(),item_detail8.getIngredients(),item_detail8.getMethods(),item_detail8.getImageNumber() );
        }

        else if(value.equals("Vegetable kootu"))
        {
            Recipedetails2 item_detail9 = new Recipedetails2();
            item_detail9.setName("Vegetable kootu");
            item_detail9.setIngredients("Nice and healthy one");
            item_detail9.setMethods("This is very good for dibets people");
            item_detail9.setImageNumber(19);
            setUIScreen(item_detail9.getName(),item_detail9.getIngredients(),item_detail9.getMethods(),item_detail9.getImageNumber() );
        }

        else if(value.equals("Avial"))
        {
            Recipedetails2 item_detail10 = new Recipedetails2();
            item_detail10.setName("Avial");
            item_detail10.setIngredients("Easy to prepare and lots of vegetable");
            item_detail10.setMethods("This is very good for dibets people");
            item_detail10.setImageNumber(20);
            setUIScreen(item_detail10.getName(),item_detail10.getIngredients(),item_detail10.getMethods(),item_detail10.getImageNumber() );
        }

        else
        {
            Recipedetails2 item_detail11 = new Recipedetails2();
            item_detail11.setName("kothavarangaicurry");
            item_detail11.setIngredients("Tamilnadu special and healthy too");
            item_detail11.setMethods("This is very good for dibets people");
            item_detail11.setImageNumber(21);
            setUIScreen(item_detail11.getName(),item_detail11.getIngredients(),item_detail11.getMethods(),item_detail11.getImageNumber() );
        }

        }

public void setUIScreen(String i1, String i2, String i3, int n1){
itemName.setText(i1);
 itemIngredients.setText(i2);
 methods.setText(i3);
 itemImage.setImageResource(imgid[n1 - 1]);
}

}
```